# Javascript in chrome extension won't load, not related to isolated world

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a javascript extension for a specific website to track the clicks of the user and log the text content.

The script ran just fine when I pasted it into the console, but when I load it into the extension it doesn't seem to execute at all.

I understand that content scripts are run in isolated worlds, but my script does not depend on any variable or function from the webpage.

Maybe I need a permission in my manifest?

here is the manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Vortojo",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Saved words",
  "icons":{
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "img/icon16"
    },
    "default_title": "browser action",
    "default_popup": "browser_action/browser_action.html"
  }
}
```

and here is the javascript browser_action.js

```
var wordsWritten = document.getElementsByTagName("var");

var wordBank ={};

for (var i = 0; i < wordsWritten.length; i++){
    wordsWritten[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("vortarobobelo").length != 0){
            var wordbubble = document.getElementsByClassName("vortarobobelo")[0].children[0]
            var words = wordbubble.children

            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ){
                var word = words[i].children[0].innerText; // the word
                var translation = words[i].children[1].innerText; // the translation
                wordBank[word] = translation;
                console.log(word,translation);
            }
        }           
    })
};
```

Comment: yeah it was, shortly after I post this question I realize that was the problem. Thanks a bunch though!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code for `browser_action.html`, but presumably it is the file that loads `browser_action.js`.  That means that all of your `getElementsBy` commands are referring to the DOM of your popup page, not the DOM of the specific website.  A good reference for distinguishing popups, backgrounds, and content scripts would be the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

You're going to need to use a content script to access the DOM of the specific website.  At the moment, you won't need a background script at all.  Whether you will in the end depends on what you want to do with `wordBank`.